# How to add a new library to Codevision AVR?

Tags: avr, codevisionavr

I want to include  and  in my source code in CodevisionAVR, how can I add these libraries? is it possible to add it permanently to the program or I must copy these libraries to my source code's directory every time I want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

to add a new library to Codevision AVR, you should go to the Project/Configure/C Compiler/Paths and then pass in your library path.